# bootstrap model (popup box) from validation with easy way or without jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i create a login popup using bootstrap modal in codeigniter and i want to apply form validation on my login popup, I don't know jquery and dont want to use javascript validation
**in my view page**

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
            <div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
                                <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Username</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

can any one help me to create form_validation with easy method
or any diffrent way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing new.! You can simply add `jquery.validate.js` file in your page or you can use [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js) for jquery validation. Then just write code for validation rules and messages. Here is small example:

```
$('#loginform').validate({
        rules: {
            username: "required",
            password: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            username: "Please enter username",
            body: "Please enter password",
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
})
```

**Note:**

1. You need to add JS for Jquery file before adding CDN of validation JS.
2. Maintain versions as needed.

OR you can follow documentation on http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: after jquery script i added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>`  then it gives me error  ** Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ** but  i defind jquery script `<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>fassets/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` then whats the meanig of this error.

Comment: and code like this `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $('#loginForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    username: "required",
                    password: "required",
                },
                messages: {
                    username: "Please enter username",
                    password: "Please enter password",
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
        })
    </script>`

Comment: its working !!!!!! but problem is that iam not able to check username and password is correct because when i use `form_open()` function it redirect me to that function but jquery validation not working,how to solve this issue,plz

Comment: I can't get you for the last comment. what is `form_open` function?

Comment: how to display same popup login if user enter wrong username or password with errors

Comment: means how to redirect popup box through controller if data not match with database like`return redirect('login/how to show popup modal');`

Comment: For that you need to make ajax call for login

Comment: thanks for helping,can u plz show how to use ajax for login popup,bcaz iam stuck from this problem,plz plz